# Recovering a parameter over the bootstrap Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, request, bootstrapping

I am developing an application in Zend framework. In my **bootstrap** I have a method named `_initRoutes`:

```
public function _initRoutes(){
        $router = $this->_front->getRouter();
        $default = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(':language/:controller/:action/*',
                        array(
                            'language' => Model_Db_Option::read('site_default_language'),
                            'module' => 'public',
                            'controller' => 'index',
                            'action' => 'index'
                        ),
                        array(
                            'language' => '^[a-z]{2}$*'
                        )
        );
}
```

Hoy can I recover the language value in the `_initRoutes`??? How can I get this value in the next function `_initLocale`

PS. I know that I can recover it as parameter from request but I want to recover it in the bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

i used this

```
    $params=@$default->match($this->_front->getRequest()->getRequestUri());
    $lang=$params['language'];
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$language = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getParam('language');
```

something like this, can't test from this comp

Comment: it probably won't work, because in bootstrap the request is not yet parsed (have to be parsed by the routers first, and you are still adding them), thus you might not have any params